# Given a continuous function of many variables, how do I know when this function is equals to zero on all the corners of a unit hypercube?

Tags: differential-calculus, hypercube

Given a continuous and deriviable function of many variables, how do I know when this function is equals to zero on all the corners (or vertices) of a unit hypercube, i.e. all points, where each coordinate is equals either to 1 or 0.

I think that if I explore the function inside or/and around the unit hypercube, I will be able to tell if:

∀x<sub>1</sub>...x<sub>n</sub>: x<sub>1</sub>∈{0,1} ∧ ... ∧ x<sub>n</sub>∈{0,1} then
f(x<sub>1</sub>, ... , x<sub>n</sub>)=0 where $f: \Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$

By exploring the function, I can compute the partial derivatives of each variable and/or multiple integrals and/or gradients and/or normal vectors, etc but I don't know what exploration should I do exactly to find out the answer.

If I know how the function behaves on the half point, i.e. (0.5, ... , 0.5), which is the center of the unit hypercube, can I find the answer to my question?

Any idea?

**Note:** you can assume that the given function is analytic.

Comment: can't you just compute the function at those points?

Comment: Compute the function at those points? Let's see: If the function has exactly n different variables, then the hypercube has exactly 2^n corners (or vertices), so for instance if the function has 10 variables, then the hypercube has 2^10=1024 corners/vertices, so I will have to do 1024 computations. This is insane! I am not going to do this and I am not going to make it. No, there must be a much quicker and faster way to determine this immediately or even instantly with derivatives and/or integrals or something or exploring the center of the hypercube.

Comment: Continuity and even smoothness is insufficient: the existence of [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) means that for any $\epsilon > 0$, if you know your function $f$ and all of its derivatives everywhere but balls of radius $\epsilon$ around the vertices, that still provides no information about $f$ at the vertices. To be able to do something like you ask, you need your function to be [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function).

Comment: Okay then let's assume that the function is analytic, whatever that means. I will also edit my question now.

Comment: Be careful that you don't have [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) as a sub-problem or else a fast solution will be too hard!

Comment: SAT as a sub-problem? I don't think, but let's hope that no.

Comment: Well, $\lnot x=1-x$, $x\wedge y=xy$ and $x\vee y=x+y-xy$, so any 3-SAT is a quickly computable polynomial. On the other hand, you said that you can quickly compute the exact integral over the cube, which, by itself, is somewhat suspicious for a general function, analytic or not. What exactly is your function class?

Comment: Your comment is nice. My function class is polynomials with many variables, does not necessarily related to any boolean function or does it? Why did you say that any 3-SAT is a quickly computable polynomial? What do you mean by that?

Comment: --"No, there must be a much quicker and faster way to determine this immediately or even instantly with derivatives and/or integrals or something or exploring the center of the hypercube"--.There must be a much quicker and faster way to make everyone happy immediately or even instantly by some single action by a single person than to allow this insane civilization to run the way it runs (note that $7\times 10^9$ is just about $2^{33}$) Alas, unless we live in a computer simulation or the God exists and cares (which are the same IMHO),the chances to find it are rather slim :-)

Comment: I mean that it is a product of about $n^3$ polynomials of low degree with few terms.

Comment: So what is the answer to my question? And you know that 2^33 is a constant, not variable. n^3 is indeed polynomial.

Comment: There are polynomials, and there are polynomials.  Computing the integral of a polynomial given as a sum of monomials is easy.  Computing the integral of a polynomial given as a product of a lot of factors (as you have in the 3-SAT example) is hard.

Comment: Does the polynomial analytic function must necessarily be boolean function of 3-SAT? Computing integrals of function with many variables is hard or very long?

Comment: On the other hand, if your polynomials are sums of not too many monomials with integer coefficients, then there may be a chance to figure something out. (Robert said so faster than I). So, can you be more specific about the representation?

Comment: So then let's assume that my polynomials are sums of not too many monomials with integer coefficients as you said.

Comment: OK, then it makes sense to go and think for a while :-)

Comment: I am starting to think that my problem is another NP-Hard and NP-Complete problem. I didn't know this before. Sorry. Interesting to find it out.

Comment: OK, this case is easy: just replace any higher than $1$ degree in each monomial by the first degree and bring similar terms together after that. If you get an identically zero function, then your original polynomial was $0$ at all corners. Otherwise no.

Comment: Nice answer, but why it is a comment? It suppose to be an answer not a comment, and in case that the function f is a result of some CNF (conjunctive normal form) and thus this is too hard to tell if f is zero on all the corners of the hypercube, then it is possible to negate the CNF and get DNF (disjunctive normal form) according to de morgan's law and compute function f from that DNF. Then we need to check if function f is equals to 1, not 0, at all the corners of the hypercube, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x^m = x$ for $x \in \{0,1\}$ and $m \ge 1$,   we may assume wlog all exponents in your polynomial are $0$ or $1$.  Thus your polynomial can be written as $$P(x) = \sum_{\alpha \in A} c_\alpha x^\alpha$$
where $A$ is a collection of not too many subsets of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ and 
 $x^\alpha = \prod_{j \in \alpha} x^j$.
Thus $P$ is $0$ at every point of the hypercube iff $P(\chi_\beta) = \sum_{\alpha \in A: \alpha \subseteq \beta} c_\alpha = 0$ for every subset $\beta$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  Of course we remove all terms where $c_\alpha = 0$.  Now unless $A$ is empty, there must be some $\alpha \in A$ that is minimal (i.e. has no proper subset in $A$).  If so, $P(\chi_\alpha) = c_\alpha \ne 0$.  So the only case where $P(x)$ is $0$ at all corners of the hypercube is where $A$ is empty, i.e. the polynomial is identically $0$.

Comment: And if I want to tell whether function f is equals to 1, not 0, at all the corners/vertices of the hypercube? How much the existing method should be changed for that?

Comment: It would have to be identically $1$.

Comment: identically 0 means that function f defined to be f(x1, ... , xn) = 0 and identically 1 means that function f defined to be f(x1, ... , xn) = 1 ?

Comment: Yes (for the function written in the form I gave).

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks for the answer.